Failed to deploy Fiori app on on CloudFoundry - NoAppDetectedError - An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack FAILED
I got my SAP BTP trial account. I created a basic Fiori app via SAP Fiori tools from template on BAS. I now want to deploy it to BTP. I used npm run build to build the project, cf login to login and set endpoint. I have ui5.yaml file. I know with .mta, we create .mtar and then deploy. That option is not here on right click.
So, I used cf push complygate_services -p dist/ to deploy. That gave the error

NoAppDetectedError - An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack
FAILED

Can someone tell me the steps to deploy a Fiori app with ui5.yaml file ?





I tried adding a file "Staticfile" with root: dist. Then cf push complygate_services -b staticfile_buildpack I got the URL for my app (running) but the content rendered there is blank.
It seems staging failed.
